# PHP mp3 upload not working. JPEGS and most other file types work though

Tags: php, forms, upload

I a bit of newbie to PHP and coding pretty much. I created the site www.newbornsounds.co.uk with pure HTML and css but am now integrating membership features with PHP.
I am having trouble with my upload script, it won't allow audio uploads. I have checked that the php.ini allows upload sizes large enough and have gone through everything i can think of. When an audio file is selceted only the name is echoed and not the size or file type. By the way I am using wamp as the dev server if that has any significance.

Here is the PHP script with form inside the php file:

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database 
include("phpscripts/database.php");


 //checks cookies to make sure they are logged in 

{ 
$username = $_COOKIE['username']; 

$pass = $_COOKIE['password']; 

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error()); }

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))  

    { }

    if ($pass != $info['password']) 


        {

                    }



 else 



 {           

 header("Location: login.html"); 

 } 


//**********************************************************************************************


echo "Please wait while we attempt to upload your file...<br><br>";

//**********************************************************************************************


$target_path = "../uploads/";

$flag = 0; // Safety net, if this gets to 1 at any point in the process, we don't     upload.

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$mimetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$filename = htmlentities($filename);
$filesize = htmlentities($filesize);
$mimetype = htmlentities($mimetype);

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $filename ); 

if($filename != ""){

echo "Beginning upload process for file named: ".$filename."<br>";
echo "Filesize: ".$filesize."<br>";
echo "Type: ".$mimetype."<br><br>";

}

   //First generate a MD5 hash of what the new file name will be
   //Force a MP3 extention on the file we are uploading

$hashedfilename = md5($filename);
$hashedfilename = $hashedfilename.".mp3";

//Check for empty file
if($filename == ""){
$error = "No File Exists!";
$flag = $flag + 1;

}

//Now we check that the file doesn't already exist.
$existname = "../uploads/".$hashedfilename;

if(file_exists($existname)){

if($flag == 0){
$error = "Your file already exists on the server!  
Please choose another file to upload or rename the file on your 
computer and try uploading it again!";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;
}

//Whitelisted files - Only allow files with MP3 extention onto server...

$whitelist = array(".mp3");
foreach ($whitelist as $ending) {

if(substr($filename, -(strlen($ending))) != $ending) {
$error = "The file type or extention you are trying to upload is not allowed!  
You can only upload MP3 files to the server!";
$flag++;
}
}


//Now we check the filesize.  If it is too big or too small then we reject it
//MP3 files should be at least 1MB and no more than 6.5 MB

if($filesize > 8920600){
//File is too large

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are trying to upload is too large!  
Your file can be up to 8.5 MB in size only.  
Please upload a smaller MP3 file or encode your file with a lower bitrate.";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;
}

if($filesize < 104860){
//File is too small

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are trying to upload is too small!
Your file has been marked as suspicious because our system has 
determined that it is too small to be a valid MP3 file.
Valid MP3 files must be bigger than 1 MB and smaller than .5 MB.";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;

}

//Check the mimetype of the file
if($mimetype != "audio/mp3" and $mimetype != "audio/mpeg"){

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are trying to upload does not contain expected data.
Are you sure that the file is an MP3?";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;
}

//Check that the file really is an MP3 file by reading the first few characters of the file
$f = @fopen($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],'r');
$s = @fread($f,3);
@fclose($f);
if($s != "ID3"){

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are attempting to upload does not appear to be a valid MP3     file.";
}

$flag++;
}



//All checks are done, actually move the file...

if($flag == 0){

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {


//Change the filename to MD5 hash and FORCE a MP3 extention.

if(@file_exists("uploads/".$filename)){

//Rename the file to an MD5 version
rename("uploads/".$filename, "uploads/".$hashedfilename);

echo "The file ".  basename( $filename ). " 
  has been uploaded.  Your file is <a href='uploads/$hashedfilename'>here</a>.";

}   
else{
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

}
else {
echo "File Upload Failed!<br>";
if($error != ""){
echo $error;
}
}

?>

<div id="uploadcontainer">
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function performClick(node) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
   node.dispatchEvent(evt);
   }
 </script>
  <a href="#" onclick="performClick(document.getElementById('file'));">
   <div id="selectfile">
    <img src="images/upload.gif" width="100" height="96" alt="upload button" border="0">        <br><br>
    <input type="button" id="uploader" value="Select a file and upload it" class="button" >
   </div></a>
      <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" id="form"     method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="file"  name="file" class="noshow">
   </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
         $("#file").change(function(){
        $("#form").submit();
     });
     });
    </script>
 <br><p2>We support MP3, WAV, FLAC, AIFF and MP2 file formats</p2>
  <br><br>
  <p2><b>Problem uploading?</b> Get in touch via<a     href="mailto:artists@newbornsounds.co.uk"><b> email </b></a>and we'll help sort things out.<br>
```

**Important:** You must own the rights to all the tracks you upload and you must be an unsigned artist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted now. Turns out I had to add a bit of code into the .htaccess file. Took me a while but now we can get on with new features for NBS.

Comment: Tip: you're not checking the `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for actual success/failure - the filename information can be present even if the upload failed. Never assume the upload succeeded.